# Scroll tab bar programmatically with dynamic tabs programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, tabs

If we have more than 5 tabs... put the 5th tab as "More" tab.. then on clicking the "More" tab rest of the options will be shown in a table view...
I have created the same Dynamic tabs programmatically.

But instead of showing in more tab I need it to show it scrollable.

Here is my tab class.
I have, LoginView,testvc1,testvc2,testvc3,testvc4,testvc5,testvc6,testvc7 viewcontroller.

Loginview(contain a button)-> on click of button tab bar is open.

**TabBarVC.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TabBarVC : UITabBarController
{
    UITabBarController *tabController;

}

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *tabOrders;
@end
```

**TabBarVC.m**

```
#import "TabBarVC.h"
#import "testvc1.h"
#import "testvc2.h"
#import "testvc3.h"
#import "testvc4.h"
#import "testvc5.h"
#import "testvc6.h"
#import "testvc7.h"

@interface TabBarVC ()
{


}
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) TabBarVC *tabBarController;
@end

@implementation TabBarVC
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     self.tabOrders = @"HOME|home,LOVE|love|,MATCH|match|";   
    self.tabOrders=[self.tabOrders stringByAppendingString:@",OpenFB|www.facebook.com,OpenWeb|www.google.com,web|www.google.com,YAHOO|www.yahoo.com,GOOGLE|www.google.com"];

    //====================================================================================
    //========================= View controller used to be assign ========================
    //====================================================================================
    NSMutableArray *tabViewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSMutableArray *resttabViewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSMutableArray *tabOrderArray=[[self.tabOrders componentsSeparatedByString:@","] mutableCopy];

    for (int i=0; i<[tabOrderArray count]; i++)
    {
        NSArray *arr_tab=[[tabOrderArray objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
        NSString *tabName=[arr_tab objectAtIndex:0]; //get array name from pipe serate
        NSString *tabAction=[arr_tab objectAtIndex:1];
        if ([tabAction isEqualToString:@"home"])
        {
            UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
            testvc1 *testvc1 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"testvc1"];
            testvc1.title = @"testvc1";
            testvc1.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"homeicon"];
            UINavigationController *testvc1NavVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: testvc1];            
            [tabViewControllers addObject:testvc1NavVC];

        }

        else if ([tabAction isEqualToString:@"love"])
        {
            UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

            testvc2 *testvc2 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"testvc2"];
            testvc2.title =@"Love";
            testvc2.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"loveicon"];



            UINavigationController *testvc2NavVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: testvc2];
            [tabViewControllers addObject:testvc2NavVC];

        }

        else if ([tabAction isEqualToString:@"match"])
        {
            UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

            testvc3 *testvc3 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"testvc3"];
            testvc3.title = @"MATCH";
            testvc3.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"matchicon"];


            UINavigationController *testvc3NavVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: testvc3];
            [tabViewControllers addObject:testvc3NavVC];


        }
        else
        {
            UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

            testvc4 *testvc4 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"testvc4"];

            testvc4.title = tabName; //TabTitle
            testvc4.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_rest"];

            UINavigationController *testvc4NavVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:testvc4];
            [resttabViewControllers addObject:testvc4NavVC];
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<[resttabViewControllers count]; i++) {
        [tabViewControllers addObject:[resttabViewControllers objectAtIndex:i]];
    }

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:15/255.0 green:68/255.0 blue:140/255.0 alpha:1.0]];

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];


    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:15/255.0 green:68/255.0 blue:140/255.0 alpha:1.0];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = 0.7f;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;


     UINavigationController* morenav = self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController;
     morenav.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];;
     morenav.navigationBar.barTintColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:15/255.0 green:68/255.0 blue:140/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:
     @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]}];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:
     @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]}];

       [self.tabBarController.tabBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:248/255.0 green:248/255.0 blue:248/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
    [self setViewControllers:tabViewControllers];
    self.customizableViewControllers = nil;
    [self setSelectedIndex:0];




    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@end
```

**to open tab bar i called**

```
-(IBAction)openTab:(id)sender
{
UIStoryboard *storyboard  = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
            UITabBarController *tbc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarController"];
             [self presentViewController:tbc animated:NO completion:nil];



}
```

My Storyboard have below uiviewcontrollers with no segue connection with each other.

```
1) UITabBarController (with class name tabbar and  with identifier UITabBarController)
2) UIViewcontrollers
```

testview1,testview2,testview3,testview4,testview5,testview6,testview7

**I need it to be scrollable like this image with dynamic tabs**
[image]

Comment: Are you using [This][1 : https://github.com/Marxon13/M13InfiniteTabBar ]

Comment: what is the issue you are faced ?

Comment: my tab bar contain more items...i need it to be on scroll view like M12InfiniteTabbar....but my tab bar should be dynamic...(its working perfect with more tab navigation) but i need it to be scrollable...as per my client's demand

Comment: This can't "just work". You either need to write your own implementation or use that library you're talking about.

Comment: i need to implement my own...but i need to know how to replace more tabs with scroll one....

Comment: I am coding in Swift, can I use this?

Comment: yes you can do it in swift